# Delete trigger does not invokes

Tags: trigger, delete

trigger :

```
if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for(OrderLineItem__c ol: trigger.old){
            List<OrderLineItem__c> order=[Select Id, Student_Roll_No__c,ShippingStatus__c,RewardPoints__c,
                                          LevelValuePoint__c ,Quantity__c from OrderLineItem__c];
            RewardTriggerHandler.DeleteReward(order);

        }
    }
```

handler class :

```
public static void DeleteReward(List<OrderLineItem__c> order1){       
        //List<OrderLineItem__c> order=[Select  Student_Roll_No__c,ShippingStatus__c,RewardPoints__c,
        //                                      LevelValuePoint__c ,Quantity__c from OrderLineItem__c];
        List<Student__c> student=[Select RollNo__c,TotalRewardPoints__c from Student__c];       
        for(OrderLineItem__c ol:order1)
            {   
                for(Student__c sd:student){
                    if(sd.RollNo__c==ol.Student_Roll_No__c){
                        if(ol.ShippingStatus__c=='Shipped'){
                            sd.TotalRewardPoints__c-=ol.RewardPoints__c;    
                        }   
                    update sd;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: First, you did not provide any context ore the test of the trigger code so the reasons why it did not invoke could only be a guess. Did you include the delete in the signature? Second, if it did invoke, you would be processing all line items in the system as you did not filter your query.

Comment: You've got quite inefficient code by putting a select statement in a for loop in your trigger. Step back and rewrite the code to query records related to the records in trigger.old. Having said that, there's an answer below that shows how to pass trigger.old into the handler class so you can do all your work there, which is a better pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included **after delete** statement in your trigger entry point. Remove all the DML operations therein for Loop. Also, need not to query on OrderLineItem__c for this use case. Always have the filters in place to target related records only while querying.
Try code below:

Trigger:

```
if(Trigger.isDelete){
   RewardTriggerHandler.DeleteReward(trigger.old);
}
```

Handler Class:

```
public static void DeleteReward(List<OrderLineItem__c> orderLineItemList ){
    Set<String> rollNumbSet = new Set<String>();
    for(OrderLineItem__c orderLineItem : orderLineItemList ) {
       rollNumbSet.add(orderLineItem.Student_Roll_No__c)
    }
   Map<Integer, Student__c> studentMap = new  Map<Integer, Student__c>();
   for( Student__c student: [Select RollNo__c,TotalRewardPoints__c from 
                            Student__c Where RollNo__c IN :rollNumbSet]
   ) {
       studentMap.put(student.RollNo__c, student);
   }       
   for(OrderLineItem__c ol: orderLineItemList ) {
       if(ol.ShippingStatus__c !='Shipped'
       || false == studentMap.containsKey(ol.Student_Roll_No__c) ){
          continue;
       }

       Student__c student = studentMap.get(ol.Student_Roll_No__c);
       student.TotalRewardPoints__c-=ol.RewardPoints__c;          
    }
    update studentMap.values();
}
```

Apart from this, specifying the relation between the Student__C and OrderLineItem__c would be really helpful to optimize the code further. Also, you should have RollNo__c unique on the Student__c object.